# Why do hops before VPN server not reflect in traceroute?

Tags: vpn, protocol-theory, traceroute, site-to-site, remote

I'm using a remote-site VPN (ProtoVPN).

When I tracert to the IP address of the VPN server, the hops through my ISP and other intermediate hops before the VPN sever are shown.

But when I tracert to other addresses, say google.com, these intermediate hops are not shown. Why?

Can VPN affect the traceroute protocol?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Traceroute is not a protocol.  It is an application that uses ICMP (Windows) or UDP (*nix) packets with short TTL values.  It relies on ICMP error messages to determine the hops.
2. VPN tunnels act as a single hop, so yes using the tunnel will affect your traceroute results.